# AndroidX navigation navigateUp twice

Tags: android, android-navigation, androidx

I am using the new AndroidX navigation framework.

I have a few fragments all linked in a navigation chain.

FragmentA --> FragmentB --> FragmentC

FragmentC has a Cancel button that should send me up all the way back to FragmentA.

Should I do the following:
on FragmentC call the method:

```
 Navigation.findNavController(view).navigateUp();
```

then on FragmentB listen to some callback and using some passed parameter or argument trigger another navigateUp() function from FragmentB

or is there some method that will do the equivalent of navigateUpTwice()

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What I ended up doing was

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack(R.id.fragmant_a,false)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with this, it works for me.

```
findNavController().navigateUp()
findNavController().navigateUp()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This method does work, however I noticed that the performance was a bit worse.

Answer (score 4):

In your navigation.xml file under the action that you have created to navigate to starting fragment (FragmentA in your case) add the following

```
<action
....
app:popUpTo="@id/fragmentA"
app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>
```

This will pop up all the fragments until FragmentA and will exclude FragmentA since **popUpToInclusive** is set to **false**.

**Edit:**
The full form of your action under FragmentC tag of your navigation.xml file will be something similar to this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/FragmentC"
    android:name="com.yourdomain.FragmentC"
    android:label="FragmentC">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragmentC_to_fragmentA"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentA"
        app:popUpTo="@id/fragmentA"
        app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>
</fragment>
```

Comment: The missing piece here is the description of the way to get back to FragmentA.

Comment: @heiligbasil Added on the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can set pop To FragmentA in your action from FragmentB --> FragmentC  and when then you press back it goes to Fragment A instead of Fragment B

Comment: But what if back button should got back to Fragment B but the cancel button should go back to Fragment A?

Comment: This is accurate. If only it had a bit more detail and some actual code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

If you have situation like @flagg10ma in his answer, you can get info about previous destination and then use its `id` in the `popBackStack()` call. Like this:

```
NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
NavBackStackEntry prevEntry = navController.getPreviousBackStackEntry();
if (prevEntry == null) {
  // There is no previous destination, so just pop once normally
  navController.popBackStack();
  return;
}
// Pop to previous destination and then pop that destination too (as we use inclusive=true)
navController.popBackStack(prevEntry.getDestination().getId(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found myself in a situation where I had to `navigateUp()` twice, but with a twist: I could reach the view through several paths. Think of it like this:

Fragment A --> Fragment C --> Fragment D

Fragment B --> Fragment C --> Fragment D

In a normal situation, using the `popTo` xml attribute or the `popBackStack()` method would work. However it is unusable here. Fortunately, what you can do is:

```kotlin
val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
navController.navigateUp()
navController.navigateUp
```

As other people have pointed out, this is absolutely not optimised performance-wise. In any situation where you can reach Fragment D through a single path, use `popTo` instead.